# about algorithm related to palindrome

Tags: algorithm, palindrome

Working on a problem below, and with a test case, my question is why a single character 'b' is a palindrome?

```
Given a string s, partition s such that every substring of the partition is a palindrome.

Return the minimum cuts needed for a palindrome partitioning of s.

For example, given s = "aab",
Return 1 since the palindrome partitioning ["aa","b"] could be produced using 1 cut.
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: BTW, I am also confused what means min-cut, could anyone show me a case where there are multiple cut solutions in a string to have different palindrome? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definition of palindrome from wikipedia:

> A palindrome is a word, phrase, number, or other sequence of characters which reads the same backward or forward.

A single character String is palindrome because it satisfies this condition.

Min cut means the minimum number of cuts you need to put so that all the substrings are palindrome.

Here is the simplest example:
`s="aaaabbbb"`

MinCuts should be `1` : `"aaaa", "bbbb"`

But in the given example you can have `3,4,5,6 etc` cuts.
Example with 3 cuts: `"aa", "aa", "bb", "bb"`

Also there will always be a solution with `minCuts = stringLength-1` as every single character is a palindrome

Comment: oops. fixed. Thanks @Hurkyl

Comment: Thanks pgiitu, do you have an example of non-consecutive (and non-single) character which have multiple cut methods?

Comment: How about this `abaabatimmit`. 1 cut `abaaba`, `timmit`. 2 cut `aba`,`aba`,`timmit`

Comment: Thanks pgiitu, smart and smart. Mark your reply as answered.